# Vertex Colors from imported glTF in three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf, assimp

I'm trying to understand the use of vertex colors on imported models within three.js.

In my use case, I have a source DXF file, which has been converted to a glTF file using Assimp.

When I import the resulting glTF file into Sketchfab, the 3d model displays all the correct and original colors that were used within the source DXF file.

[image]

When I import the same glTF file into three.js however, the colors are all different.

[image]

Within both three.js and Sketchfab the materials applied to each object within the scene are set to use vertex colors.

Can someone please explain why these results might be different, or any approach I could take to maintain the original colors within three.js

[Link to the glTF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUmGBJ4v3Gy7dDIm-Zv7u6-x60mYfRhU/view?usp=sharing)

[Link to the glTF .bin file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SkvCOPTGJkIEXOoA6pMqEMRKyLNAfcY4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you mind sharing the glTF model in this thread?

Comment: Sure thing, links to both glTF and associated bin file added.

Comment: I've imported the asset into a three.js based [glTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/), [Babylon.js sandbox](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) and Sketchfab and the result is always identical. It looks like in your second screenshot.

Comment: ahhh, your right.  I thought i had imported the glTF into Sketfab, but instead I had imported the source DXF file. I'm assuming then there is a problem in the conversion from DXF to glTF?

Comment: Yes, it seems so.

Comment: Blender can import DXF and export glTF.  You have to enable the DXF importer under Edit->Prefs->Addons.  That might be worth a try.

Comment: I have previously tested the Blender DXF import, however, it appears that Blender does not import or map through any vertex colors or materials for imported DXF files resulting in an all-white model.